# How to delete particular nodes within a nested object tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, iteration

Here is where my algorithm skills ends. I can traverse through the object and find a certain object but I'm not able to delete the object in the same time.

Here is the object

```
const obj = {
    children: [{
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 'a1',
                        type: 'a1_type'
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'a2',
                        type: 'a2_type'
                    }
                ],
                key: 'root',
                type: 'root_type'
            },
            {
                key: 'error',
                type: 'error_type'
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

The object with the key === 'error' object can be in any children array. I want to find it and delete the object that contains the key.

The output should be like that:

```
let output = findAndDeleteObjByKeyAndType('error', 'error_type')

output = {
    children: [{
        children: [
            {
                children: [
                    {
                        key: 'a1',
                        type: 'a1_type'
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'a2',
                        type: 'a2_type'
                    }
                ],
                key: 'root',
                type: 'root_type'
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array methods like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Arrayevery) can come in handy here:

```js
const object = {
  children: [{
    children: [{
        children: [{
            key: 'a1',
            type: 'a1_type'
          },
          {
            key: 'a2',
            type: 'a2_type'
          },
          {
            key: 'error',
            type: 'error_type'
          }
        ],
        key: 'root',
        type: 'root_type'
      },
      {
        key: 'error',
        type: 'error_type'
      }
    ]
  }]
}

function purgeAll (object, target) {
  if (object.children) {
    const keys = Object.keys(target)
    object.children = object.children.filter(o => 
      !keys.every(k => target[k] === o[k]) && purgeAll(o, target)
    )
  }
  return object
}

let output = purgeAll(object, {
  key: 'error',
  type: 'error_type'
})

console.log(output)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Combining filter in the return statement was the missing link. Thanks @gyre